# Change Android layout from Relative to Linear

Tags: android, android-layout

I just started creating android apps, but i have a problem changing the `layout`, every time when i create new android project , it gives me `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, (well, basically i am following the book instruction, but it doesn't teach me how to change it) I assume there must be a default setting so that i can change the `Relativelayout` to `LinearLayout` .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the `Parent` of your `layout XML` file follow these steps:

- Right click your `layout` folder in `res` folder from project folder
  in eclipse. (`<project-folder/res/layout>`)
- Choose option `New -> Other...`. Refer picture: [image: select layout folder]
- Choose `Android Layout XML file` option from here. [image]
- Press `Next` and select `LinearLayout` as `Root Element` and give `File Name`. Press Finish[image]
- Now your `Layout XML` has the root element as `LinearLayout`

Comment: These actions can **NOT** change default **root** layout .

Comment: @sam I was mentioning the steps how to create a new layout xml file with different root element, in eclipse. This answer was accepted by the thread initiator at that time. May be he might be looking for a similar solution.

Comment: yep ! but right now in `android studio` you can't do . and because in google search  this question is first i want help

Comment: @sam In android studio, you can just change the parent layout by typing in the starting tag. The closing tag will automatically changed by Android Studio. Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: i mean change default Root `Layout` when create a new layout . otherwise default root element for all layouts is `constraintlayout` and you can change it

Comment: @sam I see... I got your point. Please see this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261712/how-to-switch-from-the-default-constraintlayout-to-relativelayout-in-android-stu/42261842. Please see the third answer from `nexus5geozhi q` or `Amir Poursadegh`.

Answer (score 19):

Replace the following tags :

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    ... >

</RelativeLayout>
```

by those :

```
<LinearLayout
    ... >

</LinearLayout>
```

In addition, you should remove the following from your TextView attributes :

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

because they apply for the relative layout and not the linear layout.

Comment: You should add `android:orientation="vertical"` if you want it that way - it defaults to `horizontal`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Eclipse, just:
Rigth click, change layout and select the layout of your choice.

[Img example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07FuP.png)

[image]

Comment: All the other answers were also correct, and it is true that an easier way is to just change the text in the xml directly, but this is what I was looking for - how to do it the "eclipse" way. Thanks.

Comment: @RainwalkerJake do you know if there is a similar feature in Android Studio? The default seems to always be Relative Layout and I never realise until it's to late, and hate there is no easy way to just change to Linear like there is in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to change this tag `<RelativeLayout ...>` with `<LinearLayout ...>` , and don't forget to close it with same Layout

Answer (score 2):

In Latest versions of **android studio** i believe this will be the way to do it.

**Go to res-> layout folder** and Right Click on it and you get a sidebar asking for what type of file you want to create

Go to -> **Edit File Templates** option.

[image]

You will see this dialog opened. 
You see both options right there inside **Other tab** These options are **LayoutResourceFile.xml** and **LayoutResourceFile_vertical.xml**

[image]

Change the **${ROOT_TAG}**  to LinearLayout in both of these **LayoutResourceFile.xml** and **LayoutResourceFile_vertical.xml** and you will always get **LinearLayout** as parent for future.

[image: Change]

Answer (score 0):

When you create new XML file at that time you can assign layout to it.But when you create new project at that time you can not change layout you have to change it after creation of project.So go to .xml tab in XML file there you can edit layout. Hope this helps.