# Changing default layout

Tags: android

I'm a noob to android development and I'm going along with a book that uses linearlayouts,but when I create a project it creates relativelayouts. While I know that I can manually chance this in a short amount of time. I'm wondering is there a way to set eclipse to generate my projects with linear by default?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859073/change-android-layout-from-relative-to-linear

Comment: a selection comes up with the latest SDK. Just choose linear layout when creating an activity/layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your book uses a older version of the android sdk. In this version, the linearlayout was created by default. This later changed to relativelayout, but that explains why your book uses linearlayout. I believe you cannot change this. Just continue as you do now.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/knERro9UdHI

Answer (score 0):

Make your own blank layout .

Then go to window > Store current layout as default in android studio from top tool bar .This layout will become your default .You can restore your settings by same tab .You can use your own layout

Make sure that the layout which is open or in focus will set as a default so   make sure that right file was open at the time of setting default layout .