# How to change the default behaviour of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

Can we change the default Build behavior of Android Studio from *Constraint* to *Relative* Layout?

**Problem:** Sometimes it takes more time to Clean/Rebuild my project. And I never use Constraint Layout, so I want to set the build behavior of Android Studio from `Constraint Layout` to `Relative Layout`.

I want every-time I open AS, it should open Relative. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @Zaid But that's not what I meant. I want to change my default build behavior of AS and your link shows how to switch your default layout to Relative. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quite Easy - just in 3 steps**

1. Goto `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\common\root\res\layout`
2. Backup `simple.xml.ftl`
3. [Modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261712/how-to-switch-from-the-default-constraintlayout-to-relativelayout-in-android-stu/48492568#48492568) `simple.xml.ftl` to below code and save it

---

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Sample"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Tried and tested** on `Windows 10` `build:gradle:3.0.1`

- Works for every new activity in the same project and for future projects as well.
- **Note:** Need to modify the `simple.xml.ftl` file with Admin rights
- For this to work out [you don't need to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261712/how-to-switch-from-the-default-constraintlayout-to-relativelayout-in-android-stu/48082282#48082282) `layout > New > Edit File Templates...` your `layoutResourceFile` and `layoutResourceFile_vertical` by removing the `${ROOT_TAG}` - *as I have already tried but that doesn't work.*

Answer (score 1):

**Make default layout to `Relative` for current project**

First open your `.xml` file and change your `constraint` layout to `relative` layout. Then go to the top menu of your Android Studio with a project open. Then go to "Window" tab, Then select "Store Current Layout as default". If the default is not what you like, download a layout you would like as default and set it as your default layout.

**Make default layout to `Relative` for all projects**

Just modify the template layout file which is present in android studio resources

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\common\root\res\layout
```

Now edit this file `simple.xml.ftl` and change layout to your choice(**Note.** for making default relative just copy below code in your `simple.xml.ftl` file), notice that some layouts require additional elements (e. g. LinearLayout needs android:orientation), save file and create activity in Android Studio, it should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
<#if hasAppBar && appBarLayoutName??>
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
</#if>
    android:id="@+id/${simpleLayoutName}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
<#if hasAppBar && appBarLayoutName??>
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/${appBarLayoutName}"
</#if>
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

<#if isNewProject!false>
    <TextView
<#if includeCppSupport!false>
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
</#if>
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</#if>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work. It still gives Constraint Layout when I created new Activity. It would be nice, if you can provide me the documentation/link.

Comment: Heyy @RohitSharma you can now try the new solution which is added in my post

Comment: Thanks for the effort @MashukKhan I tried it but it doesn't even create an activity and when I reverted it works. I guess it's not possible. Also, have you tried it in your AS, does it work?

Comment: Whats your studio version??

Comment: Mine AS version is 3.0.1 (built on Nov.'17)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind if you modify the simple.xml, the android studio updater will detect a conflict and prevent applying the update. Keep your copy :)

Comment: Yes. That is very valid point. Thanks! I experienced this while `check for update` and after 3 unsuccessful attempts. :) Only solution that worked was to uninstall AS and download a fresh copy from `https://developer.android.com/studio/`