# how to switch from default constraint layout to relative layout in android studio version 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I have the latest android Studio 3.2.1 and it seems Constraint Layout is the default when creating a project. How can I make Android Studio use the Relative Layout as the default layout element for new projects ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch from the default ConstraintLayout to RelativeLayout in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261712/how-to-switch-from-the-default-constraintlayout-to-relativelayout-in-android-stu)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file in the left panel, rigth click on the layout folder, then new layout resource file, and select Relative Layout