# Changing the default layout root tag in Android Studio

Tags: android

Ever since I updated Android Studio to the 3.0.1 release, all activities created have `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` as the root layout. I've never used ConstraintLayout. How can I change studio to create activities with say LinearLayout, instead?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859073/change-android-layout-from-relative-to-linear

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this myself, but try the following as stated by this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48082282/9217218

1) click any folder u used to create layout or Activity

2) then "New>> Edit File Templates
then

3) go to "Other" tab

4) select "LayoutResourceFile.xml" and "LayoutResourceFile_vertical.xml"

5) change "${ROOT_TAG}" to "RelativeLayout"

6) click "Ok"